# Free() not freeing memory

Tags: c, heap-memory, free

I don't get why the free here is not working and i still get 5 in the printf.
Should i just point the p value to NULL?
I've searched many threads but didn't find any helpful informations about this.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){
  int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *p = 5;
  free(p);
  printf("%d\n",*p);
}
```

Comment: It is freeing memory and by accessing it after it was fred you are invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: you can just copy and run the code, i get 5 as output which seemed strange because it's the same value which was freed

Comment: You should read about what the *undefined behavior* means. What would you expect it to print?

Comment: What did you expect to be printed?

Comment: You are not allowed to read from that address any more. Therefore the content should not matter for you.

Comment: random value or i get an error since memory should be empty, i don't get what the free did here

Comment: If you rent a car and return it to the owner afterwards, the car doesn't disappear and it doesn't get "cleared" in any way. You just are no longer allowed to touch it. Don't expect anything different when using `free`.

Comment: The concept of "empty memory" doesn't really exist when you go down close to the hardware. There is just reserved memory and free memory.

Comment: `free()` tells the memory allocator that **you** don't access the memory any more. It can assign it to any other allocation. But, you access it without any other part of the program touching it. Why should it have random contents, then? -- There is no such thing as "_empty memory_".

Comment: Well thanks for the explanation but if you are not allowed to access the memory that has been freed, how did i access it without an error or warning?

Comment: @Demha In C when you have _undefined behavior_ (e.g. if you do something you are not allowed to do like here) there will generally not be any warning or error. It will just behave in undefined ways. It is up to the programmer to make sure that their code doesn't have undefined behavior.

Comment: Same way as you can access the returned car and not get caught. By accident.

Comment: C has rules that govern the behavior of C programs. Sometimes the rules say that an error must be thrown. Other times the rules say that the result is "undefined" and there is no requirement to throw an error. It's up to you to avoid undefined behavior, though some tools may help point out where such behavior might present itself.

Comment: so these are vulnerabilities programmers should pay attention to,
Clear enough! Thank you everyone you saved my day.

Comment: Incidentally, there are some implementations that clear memory after `free()` (I had to diagnose a weird bug on AIX a long time ago because of this) but this behavior should not be relied upon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function is called `free` not `erase`, it does not "erase" the memory pointed by the pointer, it merely allows that area of memory to be used for something else. `printf` printed the previous value, meaning that nothing else happened to use the memory that has been just freed.

Regardless, you are still attempting to access a memory that no longer belongs to you, and hence invoking undefined behaviour. The code may crash, or print the previous value, or print garbage, or it might as well draw a unicorn to the console, this is what makes undefined behaviour ...undefined.